# Как перевести ANSI строку в Unicode?

Tags: windows, c, mfc, atl, c++

Нужно из строки LPSTR получить строку LPWSTR, используя возможности MFC/ATL и, желательно, не используя прямые вызовы функций семейства MultiByteToWideChar.

Comment: А почему нельзя MultiByteToWideChar ? Ведь это как раз и есть ответ на ваш вопрос. Какой ещё может быть ответ? Если речь не идёт о константе, то ничего другого не остатся, кроме как преобразовать стоку с помощью стандартных функций.

Comment: Я вопрос не совсем верно задал: можно и MultiByteToWideChar, но поскольку весь код на MFC, то лучше избегать прямых вызовов, потому что они затрудняют понимание кода и его поддержку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В чистом C++ остается только MultiByteToWideChar из Windows API: он как раз и создан для подобных целей. А в MFC/ATL есть спец макросы (подозреваю, это обертки над MultiByteToWideChar).

```
void StringFunc(LPSTR lpsz)
{
   USES_CONVERSION;

   LPWSTR x = A2W(lpsz);
   // Do something with x
   wprintf_s(L"x is %s", x);
}
```

Взято оттуда: [ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть подозрение, что можно использовать ненавистный мною CString. Конструировать его из нужного типа и при необходимости - приводить к тому, что необходимо.

Comment: Это верно, CString можно присваивать любую строку и типа char* и типа wchar_t*. CStringW unicode="ansi";

Answer (score 0):

В С++ чтобы перевести в юникод нужно написать так L"..."
Перед ковычками поставить L.

Comment: Это верно, но это не совсем то: это когда прописывается константа в коде. Интересно, как превратить строчное значение ANSI, которое храниться в переменной, в строчное значение Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

RtlCreateUnicodeStringFromAsciiz().